# Livewire crud con modales

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire

Amigos buscando info no he encontrado como implementar un modal en un crud con livewire 3 si alguien tiene un repositorio donde lo implemente para poderlo estudiar ya que no he encontrado ejemplos quiza no he realizado la busque bien. gracias

Comment: Podrías chequear en este curso de [Livewire 3 desde cero](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DaHVPZgHX4GQ&ved=2ahUKEwijgeW5uI2FAxU_fTABHby4ACAQtwJ6BAgQEAI&usg=AOvVaw0V_o7T_4Am67HzLhEijnb6), está en español.